# Jquery : fadeIn hidden element in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've to fadeIn hidden image in callback .

```
<img src="images/bottle.png" id="bootle" >
```

css(in head) for this image

```
#bootle {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now, in an animate function I am  trying to fadeIn this bottle once animation is done. this is how I do it

```
function () {
    $('#bootle').css({
        visibility: 'visible'
    }).fadeIn(5000);
} //its  callback
```

but this one first shows it without fade effect and if I try to use fadeIn first that does not work what should I do ?

Comment: **1.** Don't use `visibility` use `opacity: 0` on the element **2.** Use `fadeIn` on the element. `$('el').fadeIn();`

Comment: Can you change `visibility: hidden` to `display: none`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `visibility: visible`, hide the element (e.g., `display: none`, which is what jQuery's `hide` method does), and then `fadeIn`:

```
$('#bootle').css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn(5000);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $('#bootle').css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#bootle {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Molf.png?s=32&g=1" id="bootle">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can combine the `hide` into the `css` call:

```
$('#bootle').css({
    visibility: "visible",
    display: "none"
}).fadeIn(5000);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $('#bootle').css({
    visibility: "visible",
    display: "none"
  }).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#bootle {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Molf.png?s=32&g=1" id="bootle">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Same result either way.

Or as Tushar suggested in a comment, if you don't need the layout space used up (which is what `visbility: hidden` does), you could just use `display: none` in the CSS in the first place; then you don't need the `css` or `hide` call at all:

```css
#bootle { display: none }
```

```js
$('#bootle').fadeIn(5000);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $('#bootle').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#bootle {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Molf.png?s=32&g=1" id="bootle">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note how the button moves, because it's below the image and `display: none` takes the image completely out of the layout, whereas `visibility: hidden` reserves the room for it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `visibility: hidden;` use `opacity: 0`. Then you can use jQuery `.animate()`:

```
$('#bootle').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 5000);
```

`.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` work with the css `display` property.